# Please recommend a layout gems for RoR development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, css

I am doing my application using RoR, which make me very annoying is the layout issue, I know the RoR have a really great MVC to isolate the UI out or the application logic, but it is still really annoying to work with CSS across different browsers. Is there any way to reduce that work load? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you described (if I understand it correctly) has nothing to do with Rails and MVC. CSS and browser compatibility problems are separate from server-side frameworks - I mean, they are the same whatever language or framework you use.

However, there are tools that can ease the pain, for instance, [here](http://billsaysthis.com/content/compass-blueprint-rails.php) is a good article on using [Compass](http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass) gem and [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) (btw, it also mentions [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which you may accidentally fall in love with, and these are IMO huge).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly , the answer to that is no . How hard you try , if your layout is even slightly complex , you need to take care of cross browser issues . This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694544/cross-browser-development) has a few good suggestions and tools available that maybe can speed you up .

Answer (score 0):

HAML is the best option for you .I am using HAML last one year its very fast after familarize on that