# maintenance of website in different browsers

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-browser development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694544/cross-browser-development)

how to maintain my website in different browsers

i want to display same look and feel in different browsers

i faced the problem in my website in different browsers how to avoid this
problem if any program is needed to solve this problem
please guide me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694544/cross-browser-development) Also review questions tagged [cross-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-browser).

Comment: I see the `java` tag on your question. Are you using client-side Java on your website? (Java is not a synonym for JavaScript)

Answer (score 3):

This is the perennial problem. The best you can do is:

1. Use a `DOCTYPE`. It doesn't much matter what `DOCTYPE` you use, but use one. This tells the browser to use its standards-compliant mode. (The degree to which it will actually *be* standards-compliant will vary, but it tells the browser to at least try.)
2. Make sure your pages [validate](http://validation.w3.org) according to that `DOCTYPE` (or at least *mostly* validate; if you're using an older `DOCTYPE` but need custom attributes, they won't validate).
3. Decide which browsers you will support. I don't mean you're not shooting for complete compatibility, but you have limited resources (see next point). So find out what your target audience use, and draw a line somewhere. Net Applications and StatCounter have browser statistics pages [here](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2) and [here](http://gs.statcounter.com/), and they likely represent different audiences; they may be a place to start, but of course the gold standard is your own logs.
4. **Test, test, test** with your target browsers. Not at the end, when you have things all pretty in your preferred browser; *throughout the development cycle* so you don't go too far down a path and then find that that just won't work in something you need to support.