# Find design Problems (html,css)

Tags: asp.net, html, css, cross-browser

i have some ASP.NET pages.
pages does not appear in FireFox4 same IE9.
i want to find my HTML or CSS Design problems.
i hared that [this](http://validator.w3.org/) is a tool for finding problems.
but i can't use it because my ASP.NET Page contains some usercontrols.
I am looking for a way to find my design problems(tool , tip , etc).
another note is i am using jQuery UI plugins in my site.

Comment: Hmm, the process of fixing cross-browser problems is pretty much the same, regardless of what the content is. I have a duplicate in mind, hang on

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694544/cross-browser-development)

Comment: @pekka my question is not just about Cross-browser development . i asked for some tool.

Comment: It doesn't matter what controls you are using.  The validator service checks the generated HTML and CSS, not your code-behind markup.

Comment: the question I link to contains a huge list of tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use Chrome Developer Tools / Firebug / IE 8 Developer Tools to take a peek at the HTML being generated to look for any glaring errors. It can also help catch some jQuery issue that might be causing you grief.

Outside of that, [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is a nice program that could help diagnose some stuff for you as well.

One thing to realize is that every browser renders a page slightly different, despite the attempts to render them in a "universal" manner. If you're really looking for the small differences, you can check out the [SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx) tool that comes with Microsoft Expression Web