# How do you develop for cross browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you develop for cross browser compatibility?

How do you develop and ensure that end products are capable of running on most browsers?

JavaScript and DOM:

```
JQuery 
EXT JS
```

CSS:

```
CSS Mastery (Book resource)
```

What other techniques do you employ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-browser development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694544/cross-browser-development)

Comment: Not really a valid SE question, unfortunately--though it's certainly a good question. If anything, this should be in the wiki (and likely already is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google these phrases/trends:

- graceful degradation
- progressive enhancement
- responsive design
- design for mobile first
- ARIA standards

For the most part, it's not too hard: hire good designers (visual, UX, dev) that understand the medium. Code to standards and best practices. Ignore IE if you are allowed to. ;)

Comment: Excellent list and comment. We always use a modern browser for initial testing. That way we know our code will most likely work everywhere but IE. Then we spend some significant amount of time writing hacks for IE.

Answer (score 2):

There are a wide range of books that cover certain areas of the subject. You also need to be aware of CSS bugs exhibited by certaIn browseErs. You may wish to read something like CSS Mastery, for example.

You can use something like http://browsershots.org to test your design in a wide range of browsers before launching.